# Is it a good idea using UserId from aspnet membership table as a foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I am creating a table that keeps the user id of logged in users. I was wondering if there is any drawback to using the UserId column as the reference column for the table I am creating? Thank you.

Comment: Depends of your specific scenario. It can work. Ask yourself if the data you want to be a key is going to be unique, (no multi-account logging).

Comment: I am using the UserId, which is a GUID column I believe; so, even if there are multiple applications and the users from those applications are stored in the same table, the id should be unique I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to link data from another table (such as user profile data) to the SQL Membership user, using the UserId is fine, in my experience.

In code, you can then do something like this to get a user's info:

```
var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var user = Membership.GetUser(username);
var userid = user.ProviderUserKey as Guid?;

// Look-up user info based on UserId GUID
var info = QueryOtherTables(userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it on occasion, one thing you  don't want to start doing though is sending it back and forth to other pages via querystring.  If you do, at least Encrypt it.

http://everymanprogrammer.com/index.php/passing-encrypted-parameters-to-your-querystring-the-right-way-to-do-it/